# Calling user defined javascript function on jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to call a user defined JavaScript function on a jQuery element, and though I've seen several topics on here about it, I'm still having a bit of trouble applying their logics to my situation.
Here's what i've tried so far:

**Javscript & jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

// JavaScript function     
     nl2br = function (str, is_xhtml) {
            var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br ' + '/>' : '<br>';
            return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
        }



    // jQuery Call
        if ( ! $('.mediaDesc:contains("p")').length || ! $('.mediaDesc:contains("div")').length || ! $('.mediaDesc:contains("span")').length ) {
                nl2br(this);
            }

    }); //end document ready
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mediaDesc">
Hello World!
I am text on a new line soon to have a br tag before me!    
</div>
```

My goal is to dynamically find div's with a class of **mediaDesc** to see if their inner content contains html tags such as p,span, or div. If not, then apply the nl2br JavaScript function to it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  Are there any errors on the console?  Does the jQuery code run at all?  Is the `if` condition satisfied?  Do the selectors find the elements you expect them to find?  Does your function get called?  Step through this in a debugger, you'll be able to find useful information to help us assist you.

Comment: you're passing an object reference `this` to `nl2br` but the argument looks like it requires a string (the content you are trying to affect). IOW it *seems* perhaps you want something more like this `nl2br($(this).html());`

Comment: Is that the full extend of your javascript? There's several things that are probably causing the issue: 1) Needs to be in a document ready function, so it runs *after* all the html is rendered: `jQuery(function($) { ... put your script in here ... });` - also, I'm not sure, but I believe you'll need to change from `nl2br(this)` to `nl2br($(this))` - there is a difference... - plus, as @CrayonViolent points out, the nlbr() function is set up to parse a string, but you're passing it the element object...

Comment: @cale_b It is indeed in a document ready function, and I've used the $(this) selector in nl2br as well and the code still does not execute as desired.

Comment: Then it's likely the object-being-passed issue, where the function expects a string.  The thing is, you have to change the function to accept the object, or else change how it is called:  `$(this).val(nlbr($(this).val()));`

Comment: but in addition to that, `nl2br` looks to just return the altered content. But in your first snippet where you call it, you're not assigning the altered content back to anything. so perhaps you what you really *really* need is something more like this: `$(this).html(nl2br($(this).html()));`

Comment: do you don't need pass 2 parameters on your function?

Comment: Please add more of the surrounding code; as written it doesn't appear like it can work at all.

Comment: The $(".mediaDesc") stuff specifically won't magically run nl2br on each matching element found.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I updated my code to reflect the way I'm using it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current available info, I believe you want something like this:

```
$(".mediaDesc").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("p").length == 0 || $(this).find("div").length == 0 || $(this).find("span").length == 0)
    {
        $(this).html(nl2br($(this).html()));
    }
});
```

edit: fixed mis-use of `.contains`

http://jsfiddle.net/s8eNh/

Comment: I tried your suggestion as typed but it did not work. I updated my code to reflect the full layout of it's usage to provide better clarification.

Comment: You could throw in some `console.log` lines to see where it's going wrong; `console.log($(this));` as a start, for instance, to see if it's hitting all the .mediaDesc divs properly. I'd probably log the output of the `.contains()` calls too and see if they're returning expected values.

Comment: Ack, I'm misusing contains; hang on, I'll fix my example

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Though looking at it, how was your code different from mine, not in terms of calling $(this) but as far as the if statement goes? It' essentially the same equivalent to $("element:contains('p')");

Comment: It's not the same at all - `$(".mediaDesc")` grabs *all* elements of that type, not just one. You're then not doing anything with them. You check it, but then call `nl2br()` on document (which is what `this` refers to in your code), which has nothing to convert.

Comment: My code grabs every element of `.mediaDesc`, but then runs a loop over it (.each), and checks each individual element for the need to run `nl2br`

Comment: Oh I see, that does indeed make sense. Thanks for your efforts on this, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`.contains` is for searching text within the node. What you want is:

```
$('.mediaDesc').not(':has(p, div, span)').each(nl2br)
```

if you need to process the node and only call nl2br with `text` or `html` then do:

```
$('.mediaDesc').not(':has(p, div, span)').each(function(){
    nl2br( $(this).html() )
})
```